# Java issue with reading a text file into an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created a program that is supposed to read a text file for Integers and put them into an Arraylist, and then there are a bunch of methods to act on it. but, after some trouble shooting I am noticing that my program won't pull the integers from the text file in. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
    package project1;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.System;

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] Args) {
            Main mainObject = new Main();
            mainObject.run();
        }
        public void run() {
            **ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
            String fileName = "p01-in.txt";
            Scanner in = new Scanner(fileName);
            while (in.hasNextInt()) {
                list.add(in.nextInt());
                int line = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("%s  %n" + line);
            }
            in.close();**
            ArrayList<Integer> listRunsUpCount = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Integer> listRunsDnCount = new ArrayList<>();
            Main findRuns = new Main();
            listRunsUpCount = findRuns.FindRuns(list, 0);
            listRunsDnCount = findRuns.FindRuns(list, 1);
            ArrayList<Integer> listRunsCount = new ArrayList<>();
            Main mergeRuns = new Main();
            listRunsCount = mergeRuns.MergeRuns(listRunsUpCount, 
            listRunsDnCount);
            Main Output = new Main();
            Output.Output("p01-runs.txt", listRunsCount);
        }
```

Comment: What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: `new Scanner(String)` constructs a `Scanner` that reads from **that** `String` (not a `File`). You probably meant to pass a file there.

Comment: Every time you call **in.nextInt()** in your **while** loop you are pulling in a integer value. You make the call twice, is this intentional. Perhaps what you should be doing is placing what is read into a variable then utilizing that twice instead: `int val = in.nextInt(); list.add(val); System.out.println("%s  %n" + String.valueOf(val));`. OR put `int line = in.nextInt();` above `list.add(...)` and then change `list.add(in.nextInt());` to `list.add(line);`.

Comment: By the way, it is good practice to follow the Java Naming Conventions. Variables and method names should start with lowercase. So you should refactor the variable names `Args` and `Output` and the method names `FindRuns`, `MergeRuns` and `Output`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BufferedReader to read file content line by line.

```
try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line=reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            line = reader.readLine();
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(line.trim()));
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```